# android.view.InflateException when switching to landscape mode

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app that involves two content mains, one being for portrait the other being for landscape, However, when I switch the orientation to landscape, the app crashes. Portrait and Landscape have different layouts, the only notable difference between the two is that landscape has one more fragment within its layout.

I want to iterate that this is my first time working with landscape mode in android studio so if I made any rookie mistakes, i'm sure you'll be forgiving.

Any input is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Settings Fragment.java

```
package com.example.celebquizapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View fragment_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return fragment_view;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        RadioGroup selectionOption = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.selection_option_setting);
        setRadioButtonListener(selectionOption);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        RadioButton button = (RadioButton) v;
        boolean checked = button.isChecked();

        if (checked) {
            int chosenVal = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(button.getText()));
            Log.d("RADIOS", "Current value chosen: " + chosenVal);
            preferences.edit().putInt("numofopt", chosenVal).apply();
        }

    }


    public void setRadioButtonListener(RadioGroup radioGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            radioGroup.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Not required to save data in preferences
        // So delete on start up
        preferences.edit().clear().apply();
    }
}
```

Settings Fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SettingsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/selectionOptionLabel"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/selection_option_setting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/_2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/_3"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/_4"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/_5"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/_6"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Error message

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.celebquizapp, PID: 11657
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.celebquizapp/com.example.celebquizapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.example.celebquizapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.celebquizapp:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5187)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.example.celebquizapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.celebquizapp:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.celebquizapp:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.celebquizapp.SettingsFragment.setRadioButtonListener(SettingsFragment.java:50)
        at com.example.celebquizapp.SettingsFragment.onViewCreated(SettingsFragment.java:32)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1144)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:851)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1133)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1393)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3205)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1263)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.celebquizapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5187)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: The stack trace is saying that you're calling `getChildCount()` on a null `RadioGroup` in `SettingsFragment`'s `setRadioButtonListener()` method. Does that have separate portrait and landscape layouts, as well?

Comment: @MikeM. There are different layouts, in the landscape mode there are two fragments, while in portrait there is only one fragment.

Comment: Right, but I was asking if `SettingsFragment` itself has separate layouts, as well. However, if you mean that `SettingsFragment` is only in the `Activity`'s landscape layout, then it would seem to be a basic `NullPointerException` in that class.

Comment: @MikeM. You're right, it's a method in my fragment. For some reason this issue is not present in the portrait mode but it occurs whenever landscape is triggered. This method basically creates listeners for all the radio buttons. The RadioGroup is null for some reason.

Comment: You need to call `findViewById()` on the `View view` passed into `onViewCreated()`, not on `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> RadioGroup selectionOption = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.selection_option_setting);

It should be

```
RadioGroup selectionOption = view.findViewById(R.id.selection_option_setting);
```